# Raspbian apache2 virtual host

Tags: raspbian, web-server, raspbian-wheezy, apache-httpd

I am trying to setup virtual hosts on apache2 on Raspbian.

made a directory for www.example.com

```
wim@raspberrypi-lamp-server /var/www $ sudo mkdir www.example.com
wim@raspberrypi-lamp-server /var/www $ sudo mkdir www.example.com/htdocs
wim@raspberrypi-lamp-server /var/www $ sudo mkdir www.example.com/cgi
wim@raspberrypi-lamp-server /var/www $ sudo mkdir www.example.com/logs
```

create the virtual.conf file /etc/apache2/conf.d/virtual.conf

```
wim@raspberrypi-lamp-server /etc/apache2/conf.d $ sudo nano virtual.conf

#
#  We're running multiple virtual hosts.
#
NameVirtualHost *
```

virtual host config file

```
#
#  Example.com (/etc/apache2/sites-available/www.example.com)
#
<VirtualHost *>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@example.com
    ServerName  www.example.com
    ServerAlias example.com

    # Indexes + Directory Root.
    DirectoryIndex index.html
    DocumentRoot /var/www/www.example.com/htdocs/

    # CGI Directory
    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /var/www/www.example.com/cgi-bin/
    <Location /cgi-bin>
            Options +ExecCGI
    </Location>


    # Logfiles
    ErrorLog  /var/www/www.example.com/logs/error.log
    CustomLog /var/www/www.example.com/logs/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

enable the site

```
wim@raspberrypi-lamp-server /etc/apache2/conf.d $ sudo a2ensite www.example.com
```

reloading apache gives me

```
wim@raspberrypi-lamp-server /etc/apache2/sites-available $ sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 reload
[....] Reloading web server config: apache2apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 127.0.1.1 for   ServerName
[Wed Aug 13 12:44:40 2014] [error] VirtualHost *:80 -- mixing * ports and non-* ports with a NameVirtualHost address is not supported, proceeding with undefined results
[Wed Aug 13 12:44:40 2014] [warn] NameVirtualHost *:80 has no VirtualHosts
. ok
```

Now I can not see the index.html file in a webbrowser when I try to connect to the server.
How can I resolve the [error] VirtualHost *:80 -- mixing * ports and non-* ports with a NameVirtualHost address is not supported, proceeding with undefined results and the warning: [warn] NameVirtualHost *:80 has no VirtualHosts

does the apache process need more than write access to the config files ?
looking at the permissions all the config files are owned by root.

Comment: Have you tried commenting out the NameVirtualHost directive and restarting Apache? I've set up a few virtual hosts, and I didn't use NameVirtualHost at all.  And as stated in @stefan's answer, use *:80 instead of *.

Comment: problem solved. There was some mistake in the tutorial I was following. NameVirtualHost *:80 <VirtualHost *:80> works the tutorial had NameVirtualHost *:80 <VirtualHost *>. thank you.
Next step getting https running.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like there is more than one entry of NameVirtualHost

Try to find out that u r using the right configuration file and that no
NameVirtualhost is used before.

Your Warning "NameVirtualHost *:80 has no VirtualHosts" looks like that
is one "NameVirtualHost *:80" Entry before yours and so apache does the following:

1.) Ignoring the other NameVirtualHost Entries

2.) Cant find a matching Virtualhost, cause they need to be exactly the same, either with Portnumber or without

So use something like

---

NameVirtualHost *:80
<VirtualHost *:80>

---

Comment: I found NameVirtualHost *:80 in /etc/apache2/ports.conf
I deleted the /etc/apache2/conf.d/virtual.conf file
after enabling the sites I don't get the error anymore but still get the warning Warning "NameVirtualHost *:80 has no VirtualHosts"

Comment: NameVirtualHost *:80
<VirtualHost *:80> 
now the server reloads without any errors.